# JSON - Iterate through JSONArray

Tags: java, json

I have a JSON file with some arrays in it. I want to iterate through the file arrays and get their elements and their values.

**This is how my file looks like:**

```
{
"JObjects": {
    "JArray1": [
        {
            "A": "a",
            "B": "b",
            "C": "c"
        },
        {
            "A": "a1",
            "B": "b2",
            "C": "c3",
            "D": "d4"
            "E": "e5"
        },
        {
            "A": "aa",
            "B": "bb",
            "C": "cc",
            "D": "dd"
        }

    ]
}

}
```

**This is how far I have come:**

```
JSONObject object = new JSONObject("json-file.json");
JSONObject getObject = object.getJSONObject("JObjects");
JSONArray getArray = getObject.getJSONArray("JArray1");

for(int i = 0; i < getArray.length(); i++)
{
      JSONObject objects = getArray.getJSONArray(i);
      //Iterate through the elements of the array i.
      //Get thier value.
      //Get the value for the first element and the value for the last element.
}
```

Is it possible to do something like this?

The reason I want to do it like this is because the arrays in the file have a different number of elements.

Comment: Are you using the org.json API, or some other Java-to/from-JSON library?

Comment: If you are using `org.json.simple.JSONArray` then it is `getArray.get(i)` to access ith value of  `JSONArray` list

Answer (score 102, accepted):

Change

```
JSONObject objects = getArray.getJSONArray(i);
```

to

```
JSONObject objects = getArray.getJSONObject(i);
```

or to

```
JSONObject objects = getArray.optJSONObject(i);
```

depending on which JSON-to/from-Java library you're using.  (It looks like `getJSONObject` will work for you.)

Then, to access the string elements in the "objects" `JSONObject`, get them out by element name.

```
String a = objects.get("A");
```

If you need the names of the elements in the `JSONObject`, you can use the static utility method `JSONObject.getNames(JSONObject)` to do so.

```
String[] elementNames = JSONObject.getNames(objects);
```

> "Get the value for the first element and the value for the last element."

If "element" is referring to the component in the array, note that the first component is at index 0, and the last component is at index `getArray.length() - 1`.

---

> I want to iterate though the objects in the array and get thier component and thier value. In my example the first object has 3 components, the scond has 5 and the third has 4 components. I want iterate though each of them and get thier component name and value.

The following code does exactly that.

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class Foo
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
  {
    String jsonInput = "{\"JObjects\":{\"JArray1\":[{\"A\":\"a\",\"B\":\"b\",\"C\":\"c\"},{\"A\":\"a1\",\"B\":\"b2\",\"C\":\"c3\",\"D\":\"d4\",\"E\":\"e5\"},{\"A\":\"aa\",\"B\":\"bb\",\"C\":\"cc\",\"D\":\"dd\"}]}}";

    // "I want to iterate though the objects in the array..."
    JSONObject outerObject = new JSONObject(jsonInput);
    JSONObject innerObject = outerObject.getJSONObject("JObjects");
    JSONArray jsonArray = innerObject.getJSONArray("JArray1");
    for (int i = 0, size = jsonArray.length(); i < size; i++)
    {
      JSONObject objectInArray = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

      // "...and get thier component and thier value."
      String[] elementNames = JSONObject.getNames(objectInArray);
      System.out.printf("%d ELEMENTS IN CURRENT OBJECT:\n", elementNames.length);
      for (String elementName : elementNames)
      {
        String value = objectInArray.getString(elementName);
        System.out.printf("name=%s, value=%s\n", elementName, value);
      }
      System.out.println();
    }
  }
}
/*
OUTPUT:
3 ELEMENTS IN CURRENT OBJECT:
name=A, value=a
name=B, value=b
name=C, value=c

5 ELEMENTS IN CURRENT OBJECT:
name=D, value=d4
name=E, value=e5
name=A, value=a1
name=B, value=b2
name=C, value=c3

4 ELEMENTS IN CURRENT OBJECT:
name=D, value=dd
name=A, value=aa
name=B, value=bb
name=C, value=cc
*/
```

Comment: Programmer Bruce: I dont want to get the name for a specific element, I want to check if the array has 4 element, then get thier name and thier value or if the array has 5 elements then get thier name and value.

Comment: Are you checking if the array has 4 object components, or if an object in the array has 4 elements?  To check the number of object components in the array, use getArray.length().  To check the number of elements in a JSON object, you can use JSONObject.getNames(objects).length.

Comment: I want to iterate though the objects in the array and get thier component and thier value. In my example the first object has 3 components, the scond has 5 and the third has 4 components. I want iterate though each of them and get thier component name and value.

Comment: You keep changing the requirements.  All of the pieces of the code necessary to do what you want are already posted on this page.

Comment: Updated answer per latest requirements.

Comment: Iam sorry man, sometimes I even confuess myself. This code should do what I want to do. Thanks again.

Comment: How this can work, you are passing `int` in case of `STRING` to `getJSONObject()`. Please clarify.

Comment: coming from python, it looks like going back to assembly!

Answer (score 23):

```
for (int i = 0; i < getArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject objects = getArray.getJSONObject(i);
            Iterator key = objects.keys();
            while (key.hasNext()) {
                String k = key.next().toString();
                System.out.println("Key : " + k + ", value : "
                        + objects.getString(k));
            }
            // System.out.println(objects.toString());
            System.out.println("-----------");

        }
```

Hope this helps someone

Comment: Thanks a lot ! You made my day ! I was unable to find an example to loop over a JSONArray WITHOUT knowing key !

Answer (score 11):

```
JsonArray jsonArray;
Iterator<JsonElement> it = jsonArray.iterator();
while(it.hasNext()){
    System.out.println(it.next());
}
```

Comment: Ι tried your approach in my case and I retrieved the following error: `cannot find symbol method iterator()`

Answer (score 10):

```
for(int i = 0; i < getArray.size(); i++){
      Object object = getArray.get(i);
      // now do something with the Object
}
```

You need to check for the type:

> The values can be any of these types: Boolean, JSONArray, JSONObject,
>   Number, String, or the JSONObject.NULL object. [[Source](http://www.json.org/javadoc/index.html?org/json/JSONArray.html)]

In your case, the elements will be of type JSONObject, so you need to cast to JSONObject and call [`JSONObject.names()`](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#names%28%29) to retrieve the individual keys.

Comment: I know that the values have are of type String. How can I determine the value of the first element and the value of the last element in the array?

Answer (score 3):

To use @aianitro's efficient solution to cases like [io.vertx.core.json.JsonArray where the iterator returns Object](https://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/core/json/JsonArray.html), cast the object to JsonObject afterwards...

```
Iterator<Object> it = timeseries.iterator();
while(it.hasNext()){
    JsonObject jobj = (JsonObject) it.next();
    System.out.println(jobj);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try my (*heavily borrowed from various sites) recursive method to go through all JSON objects and JSON arrays until you find JSON elements.  This example actually searches for a particular key and returns all values for all instances of that key.  'searchKey' is the key you are looking for.

```
ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
myList = findMyKeyValue(yourJsonPayload,null,"A"); //if you only wanted to search for A's values

    private ArrayList<String> findMyKeyValue(JsonElement element, String key, String searchKey) {

    //OBJECT
    if(element.isJsonObject()) {
        JsonObject jsonObject = element.getAsJsonObject();

        //loop through all elements in object

        for (Map.Entry<String,JsonElement> entry : jsonObject.entrySet()) {
            JsonElement array = entry.getValue();
            findMyKeyValue(array, entry.getKey(), searchKey);

        }

    //ARRAY
    } else if(element.isJsonArray()) {
        //when an array is found keep 'key' as that is the array's name i.e. pass it down

        JsonArray jsonArray = element.getAsJsonArray();

        //loop through all elements in array
        for (JsonElement childElement : jsonArray) {
            findMyKeyValue(childElement, key, searchKey);
        }

    //NEITHER
    } else {

        //System.out.println("SKey: " + searchKey + " Key: " + key );

            if (key.equals(searchKey)){
                listOfValues.add(element.getAsString());
            }
    }
    return listOfValues;
}
```