# org.json.simple - How to iterate through individual objects in a JSONArray, and arrays within the individual objects?

Tags: java, arrays, json, loops, org.json

Using the org.json.simple library, how can I iterate through a JSONArray, processing its individual objects and arrays inside the individual objects?

I have found answers on how to do this for different JSON libraries but in my situation I am required to use org.json.simple.

Here is an example of what the JSONArray i need to process looks like:

```js
[
   {
      "versions":[
         {
            "rocket_version":"3.3.0.0",
            "pluginVersion":"1.0.1.0",
            "uploaded":1429350563,
            "changelog":"<ul>\r\n\t<li>ADDED: anti-suicide.imune permission<\/li>\r\n<\/ul>",
            "url":"https:\/\/dev.rocket.foundation\/wp-content\/uploads\/AntiSuicide3.zip"
         },
         {
            "rocket_version":"3.3.0.0",
            "pluginVersion":"1.0.0.2",
            "uploaded":1429283276,
            "changelog":"<ul>\r\n\t<li>FIXED: hopefully fixed the allocated memory (needs testing)<\/li>\r\n<\/ul>",
            "url":"https:\/\/dev.rocket.foundation\/wp-content\/uploads\/AntiSuicide2.zip"
         },
         {
            "rocket_version":"3.3.0.0",
            "pluginVersion":"1.0.0.1",
            "uploaded":1429196020,
            "changelog":"<ul>\r\n\t<li>FIXED: small exception every time someone suicide.<\/li>\r\n<\/ul>",
            "url":"https:\/\/dev.rocket.foundation\/wp-content\/uploads\/AntiSuicide1.zip"
         },
         {
            "rocket_version":"3.3.0.0",
            "pluginVersion":"1.0.0.0",
            "uploaded":1428923374,
            "changelog":"",
            "url":"https:\/\/dev.rocket.foundation\/wp-content\/uploads\/AntiSuicide.zip"
         }
      ],
      "author":"ApokPT",
      "name":"Anti-Suicide",
      "id":910,
      "development_stage":"Release",
      "headline":"Anti-Suicide relocation",
      "url":"https:\/\/dev.rocket.foundation\/?post_type=rplugin&#038;p=910"
   },
   {
      "versions":[
         {
            "rocket_version":"3.3.0.0",
            "pluginVersion":"1.0.0.0",
            "uploaded":1429113571,
            "changelog":"Updated needed libraries",
            "url":"https:\/\/dev.rocket.foundation\/wp-content\/uploads\/ZaupWhitelist_1.0.0.02.zip"
         },
         {
            "rocket_version":"3.3.0.0",
            "pluginVersion":"1.0.0.0",
            "uploaded":1429047352,
            "changelog":"First release",
            "url":"https:\/\/dev.rocket.foundation\/wp-content\/uploads\/ZaupWhitelist_1.0.0.01.zip"
         }
      ],
      "author":"Zamirathe",
      "name":"Zaup Mysql Whitelist",
      "id":929,
      "development_stage":"Release",
      "headline":"Whitelist in Mysql",
      "url":"https:\/\/dev.rocket.foundation\/?post_type=rplugin&#038;p=929"
   },
   {
      "versions":[
         {
            "rocket_version":"3.3.0.0",
            "pluginVersion":"1.3.5.0",
            "uploaded":1429284290,
            "changelog":"<ul>\r\n\t<li>FIXED: Possible memory leak (needs testing);<\/li>\r\n\t<li>FIXED: Reactivated strip on give kit;<\/li>\r\n\t<li>ADDED: Cooldown check for permission givekit.onjoin.&lt;kitname&gt;<\/li>\r\n<\/ul>",
            "url":"https:\/\/dev.rocket.foundation\/wp-content\/uploads\/GiveKit27.zip"
         },
         {
            "rocket_version":"3.3.0.0",
            "pluginVersion":"1.3.4.0",
            "uploaded":1429192200,
            "changelog":"<ul>\r\n\t<li>ADDED: givekit.onjoin.&lt;kit name&gt; permission<\/li>\r\n<\/ul>",
            "url":"https:\/\/dev.rocket.foundation\/wp-content\/uploads\/GiveKit26.zip"
         }
      ],
      "author":"ApokPT",
      "name":"Give Kit",
      "id":858,
      "development_stage":"Release",
      "headline":"Give a Kit to another player or yourself",
      "url":"https:\/\/dev.rocket.foundation\/?post_type=rplugin&#038;p=858"
   }
]
```

Each individual object in the whole array has a versions array and an "id" attribute. For each individual object, I need to:

1. Get the 'id' attribute's value
2. Iterate through each object in the 'versions' array and get the value of its attributes, such as 'url', 'changelog', 'pluginVersion', etc.

For each object in each versions array, I just need to call a method that accepts the id attribute, and the url/changelog/pluginVersion attributes.

How can I do this task in Java with the org.json.simple library?

**Note: I need to use the org.json.simple library!**

Comment: Does this question contain the answer you seek? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697147/json-iterate-through-jsonarray

Comment: @JohnHascall I saw that question before posting this but it doesn't seem to use the org.json.simple library. A lot of the methods it uses such as .getJSONObject() and .getJSONArray() don't exist in the org.json.simple library.

Comment: OK, I wasn't sure.  Looks like documentation for org.json.simple is pretty much limited to the README file that comes with it.

Answer (score 0):

From the README file, it appears that parsing an object just gives you some classes that extend the basic java collection classes (org.json.simple.JSONObject inherits java.util.HashMap & org.json.simple.JSONArray inherits java.util.ArrayList) so you can use all the normal java methods.  For example:

```
  String s="[0,{\"1\":{\"2\":{\"3\":{\"4\":[5,{\"6\":7}]}}}}]";

  Object obj=JSONValue.parse(s);
  JSONArray array=(JSONArray)obj;
  System.out.println(array.get(1));

  JSONObject obj2=(JSONObject)array.get(1);
  System.out.println(obj2.get("1"));

  Result:
  {"1":{"2":{"3":{"4":[5,{"6":7}]}}}}
  {"2":{"3":{"4":[5,{"6":7}]}}}
```