# Accessing JSON values into a java variable

Tags: java, json

I'm calling a method which returns a json response.

call:

```
String domainTermJson = getTermJson(domainTermId,client,gson);

Response:

{"assigned_assets":{"items":[{"_type":"database_column","_id":"b1c497ce.60641b50.42lla3a9f.di3kgbf.q6iaov.51q42k0equhf2ept2cgts","_url":"https://cs2cislp02.bns:9443/ibm/iis/igc-rest/v1/assets/b1c497ce.60641b50.42lla3a9f.di3kgbf.q6iaov.51q42k0equhf2ept2cgts","_name":"__AC_DEAACC"},{"_type":"database_column","_id":"b1c497ce.60641b50.42lla491l.o39k1ru.63p48q.57h74d2s5llcll4e429ji","_url":.
.
.
.etc...
```

What I am trying to do is capture all the _id values into a string seperated by a comma. Example below:

```
String dc_id = "b1c497ce.60641b50.42lla3a9f.di3kgbf.q6iaov.51q42k0equhf2ept2cgts", "b1c497ce.60641b50.42lla491l.o39k1ru.63p48q.57h74d2s5llcll4e429ji"
```

How can I do this with a json response?

Comment: There are many ways to do this and many tools that can help. What technologies are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the [JSON response like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697147/json-iterate-through-jsonarray)  and assign the attribute ID to the string in each iteration like this : `dc_id+=objectInArray.getString("_id");`

Answer (score 0):

You could use JSONObject library in order to get that.

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(getTermJson(domainTermId,client,gson));
JSONObject list = jsonObject.getJSONObject("assigned_assets").getJSONObject("items");
JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(list);
List<String> ids = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject obj = arr.getJSONObject(i);
    ids.add(obj.get("_id").toString());
}
```