# How to break the content of JSONArray into new lines

Tags: java, arrays, json

I am trying to break my JSON result into new lines, but finding it difficult to do.
e.g, `{"id":"1","student_id":"5013","subject1":"87","subject2":"87","subject3":"56","subject4":"76","subject5":"68","subject6":"58","subject7":"98","subject8":"67","subject9":"88"}`

to

```
    id : 1
    student_id : 5013
    subject1 : 87
    subject2 : 87
...
```

I tried using

```
    String[] stringsArray = new String[jArray.length()];
             for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                    System.out.println(stringsArray[i] = jObj.getString(i) + "\n");
}
```

but still giving same result.
Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java)

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html#toString(int)

Comment: Are you trying to parse the JSON or just pretty print?

Comment: all i want to do is just to print, i am not parsing the JSON

Comment: `System.out.println("stringsArray[i] = "  + jObj.getString(i) + "\n");`?

Comment: What output are you getting?

Comment: thanks for that, but it is still giving that same string please. talking about {"id":"1","student_id":"5013","subject1":"87","subject2":"87","subject3":"56","subject4":"76","subject5":"68","subject6":"58","subject7":"98","subject8":"67","subject9":"88"}

Comment: Have you looked at [`String::replaceAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-)?

Comment: thanks so much @bradimus, i have been able to get it using [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25683910/7000849) . I sincerely do appreciate your time.