# iterate through JSONArray in java

Tags: java, arrays

I have a JSONArray :

```
public JSNArray getItems() {
  JSONArray listjson = new JSONArray();
  JSONObject fnl_json = new JSONObject(); 
  //adding few items to fnl_json 
  listjson.add(fnl_json); 
  return fnal_json; 
}
```

I am calling getItems function, how can I iterate through fnl_json from the called function?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSON - Iterate through JSONArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697147/json-iterate-through-jsonarray)

Answer (score 2):

To iterate a `JSONArray` you can do:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject("jsonString");
JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("arrayName");
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
   JSONObject explrObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i); // you will get the json object
   //do the stuff
}
```