# I have a JSON string with some arrays in it. I want to iterate and get their elements and their values. This is how my file looks like:

Tags: java

```
{
    "results": [{
        "statement_id": 0,
        "series": [{
            "name": "sampleMeasurement1",
            "columns": ["time", "disk_type", "field1", "field2", "field3", "field4", "hostname"],
            "values": [
                ["2018-02-28T06:50:35.435Z", null, 12212, 22.44, "thisIsString", false, "server001"],
                ["2018-02-28T06:50:35.464Z", "HDD", 112, 21.44, "thisIsString1", true, null],
                ["2018-02-28T06:50:35.497Z", null, 12212, 22.44, "thisIsString", false, "server001"],
                ["2018-02-28T06:50:35.572Z", "HDD", 112, 21.44, "thisIsString1", true, null]
            ]
        }]
    }]
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is your question?

Comment: He tries to use BackSlash right now - if you know what I mean

Comment: try using gson on it.!

Comment: Using below link I tried to iterate the JSON string.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697147/json-iterate-through-jsonarray
But, unable to iterate the above mentioned json string. this data comes from influxdb

Comment: in your values array list try to send label as well.! with values.!

Comment: labels: "columns": ["time", "disk_type", "field1", "field2", "field3", "field4", "hostname"],

respective values:

"values": [
                ["2018-02-28T06:50:35.435Z", null, 12212, 22.44, "thisIsString", false, "server001"],
                ["2018-02-28T06:50:35.464Z", "HDD", 112, 21.44, "thisIsString1", true, null],
                ["2018-02-28T06:50:35.497Z", null, 12212, 22.44, "thisIsString", false, "server001"],
                ["2018-02-28T06:50:35.572Z", "HDD", 112, 21.44, "thisIsString1", true, null]
            ]

JSON string fromat data comes from influxdb.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your JSON object is saved in a file "simple.json", you can iterate over the attribute-value pairs as follows:

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("simple.json"));

JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;

for(Iterator iterator = jsonObject.keySet().iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
    String key = (String) iterator.next();
    System.out.println(jsonObject.get(key));
}
```

Or

You should instead create a JSONArray from the String and then iterate over the array. Example:

```
String jsonString = "<your-json-string>"

try {
    // create the json array from String
    JSONArray jsonRules = new JSONArray(jsonString);
    // iterate over it 
    for (int i=0; i<jsonRules.length();i++){
        JSONObject obj = jsonRules.get(i);
        ....
        ....
    }
} catch (JSONException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.influxdb.json;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class ParseNestedJson {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            String jsonString="[{\"statement_id\":0,\"series\":[{\"name\":\"sampleMeasurement1\",\"columns\":[\"time\",\"disk_type\",\"field1\",\"field2\",\"field3\",\"field4\",\"hostname\"],\"values\":[[\"2018-02-28T09:47:21.699Z\",null,12212,22.44,\"thisIsString\",false,\"server001\"],[\"2018-02-28T09:47:21.729Z\",\"HDD\",112,21.44,\"thisIsString1\",true,null],[\"2018-02-28T09:47:21.763Z\",null,12212,22.44,\"thisIsString\",false,\"server001\"],[\"2018-02-28T09:47:21.797Z\",\"HDD\",112,21.44,\"thisIsString1\",true,null]]}]}]";
            /**
             *  create the json array from String
             */
            JSONArray jsonRules = new JSONArray(jsonString);
            /**
             *  iterate over it 
             */
            JSONArray jarray=null;
            for (int i=0; i<jsonRules.length();i++){
                JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) jsonRules.get(i);
                System.out.println("series:::"+obj.getJSONArray("series"));
                jarray=obj.getJSONArray("series");
            }
                System.out.println("$$$$$$$$ COLUMNS $$$$$$$$");

            for (int i=0; i<jarray.length();i++){
                JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) jarray.get(i);
                System.out.println("columns:::"+obj.getJSONArray("columns"));

                int count=obj.getJSONArray("columns").length();
                for (int j=0; j<count;j++){
                      System.out.println("columns(j):::"+obj.getJSONArray("columns").getString(j));
                }
                System.out.println("$$$$$$$$ VALUES $$$$$$$$");
                System.out.println("values:::"+obj.getJSONArray("values"));
                int cnt=obj.getJSONArray("values").length();
                for (int j=0; j<cnt;j++){
                      System.out.println("values(j):::"+obj.getJSONArray("values").get(j));
                      JSONArray jarr=obj.getJSONArray("values");
                      /**
                       * System.out.println(jarr.get(j));
                       */
                      parseSquareBracketJson(jarr.get(j).toString());
                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public static void parseSquareBracketJson(String string) {
        /**
         * Remove square brackets
         */
        string = string.substring(1, string.length()-1);
        /**
         * Remove qutation marks
         */
        string.replaceAll("\"", "");
        /**
         * turn into array
         */
        String[] array = string.split(",");
        /**
         * Turn into list
         */
        List<String> list = Arrays.asList(array);
        System.err.println(list);
        /**
         * list.forEach(x -> System.err.println(x));
         */

    }

}
```